# How to make elements in a website always fit in the browser size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the  in my website always fit in the browser size. Right now, if I go to my website with a smaller screen, everything is messing together. Here is one  and css example in my codes

**html**

```
<div class="contactus">

<h2>Contact Us</h2>

<h3>PhoneNumber</h3>
<h3>812-123-4567</h3>
<h3>Email</h3>
<h3>qwerty@asd.com</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.contactus {
    position:absolute;
    right:20px;
    top:150px;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color:#333;
    width:100px;
    font:20px;
```

Comment: Read about [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)  
To fix issue in your case use width in percentages `width:100%`

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it responsive you need to keep the code of the CSS in relative units because whey you make it with fixed units the code will not adapt to the screen so you will have to make your code something like this:

```
div.contactus {
    position:absolute;
    right:5%;
    top:25%;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-color:#333;
    width:100%;
    font:20px;}
```

If the percentages are not ok just keep playing with them until you like it.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive media queries would be extremely helpful, but the biggest problem I'm seeing is that your container (.contactus) is not wide enough to accommodate the text you're trying to place.  Try changing the contactus width to 400px.  However, on a smaller screen, you should have a media query that updates font size and container size based on the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple fiddle to help you with your responsive issues : https://jsfiddle.net/nLxa1745/

HTML

```
<div class="main"> 
  <img class="user-pic" src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
  <div class="contact-box">
    <h4 class="user-name">Contact Us</h4>
    <ul class="info-contact">
        <li>
       phonenumber
        </li> 
        <li>
        812-123-4567
        </li>
            <li>
       email
        </li> 
        <li>
       qwerty@blabla.com
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #3f3f3f;
}

li{
  margin: 5px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.main {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 1px gray;
}

.user-pic {
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
}

.user-name {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: #B77425;
}

.info-contact {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}


@media only screen 
and (min-width : 600px) {
  .main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px; 
  }
  .user-pic {
    border-right: 2px solid gray;
    float: left;
  }
  .contact-box {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

P.S. I'd recommend a reading about headings also: [The Truth About Multiple H1 Tags in the HTML5 Era](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/the-truth-about-multiple-h1-tags-in-the-html5-era--webdesign-16824)